# Have a three state toggle slider with angular-material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I need to have three state slider:

**Off**:X--o--o

**Unknown:** o--X--o

**On:** o--o--X

[image]

But I think that the default slide toggle of angular-material doesn't support it: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview

Is there a way to extends the functionality of this control? Or what should I do to use it as a starting point if not?

Comment: this example maybe help you  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkmkvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 1):

A `toggle` is only supposed to have two states, so it may be that you want to go back to design and rethink the control to better fit the use case.

However, you can achieve this with the `slider`

link: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/examples

Set the `step` to `50` so you have (3) options - 0, 50, 100 and you can then continue as needed.

Comment: I don't really agree with you. Who has decided that a toggle has only two states? It's like checkbox, it can have 3 states. 

I really need to have a visual feedback of what are the possible values, and I need to be able to cycle between the 3 states when I click on it. I'm not sure the slider is a good fit for this

Comment: Google decided: Represents a slidable "switch" toggle that can be moved between on and off. It does not have a 3rd state like a checkbox. The slide-toggle behaves similarly to a checkbox, though it does not support an indeterminate state like <mat-checkbox>

Comment: Ok, so you were talking about the angular-material toggle, not toggle in general. That I can agree. Anyway, I'm not sure how I change the look & feel of an existing(slider) component(to make it looks like a toggle), do you have some example on how to override this? I need to put some clue that there is 3 states and have a mechanism that iterate over the 3 possible states on click.